# iPhone AlertView Text Field Keyboard not visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard

I have an alert view with a uitextfield added as a subview.

In my uitableview controller the keyboard shows fine.

[image: http://i301.photobucket.com/albums/nn76/hackmodford/c804bd91.jpg]

However in a different view I wanted to do the same thing. So instead of using a UITableView Controller I made it a UIViewController so that I could add a toolbar at the bottom of the view.

But when I display the UIAlertView the keyboard is hidden. I'm thinking it's behind the view because the alert view moves up to make room for the keyboard.

[image: http://i301.photobucket.com/albums/nn76/hackmodford/5680aaa2.jpg]

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

The reason the keyboard was being hidden was because I was dismissing a modalviewcontroller after showing the alert. For some reason it would dismiss the keyboard also I guess. Just rearranged the order an fit works fine now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try implementing the `didPresentAlertView:` method and inside set the text field to `firstResponder` like so:

```
- (IBAction)someActionThatTriggersAnAlertView:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:@"MESSAGE" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField *someTextField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    someTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    someTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    someTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

#pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate Methods

- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

[`UIAlertView` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)
[`UIAlertViewDelegate` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html)

Comment: That worked beautifully! Even better than having a delay... Thank You